"Are there any simple groups that appear as zeros of the zeta function?" by Peter Freyd; why is this consternating to mathematicians?
I would like to understand the "upsetting"-to-mathematicians nature of this question Freyd poses to demonstrate that "any language sufficiently rich that to be defined necessarily allows you to ask
questions which don't have any conceivable answer but sound as if they should" (18:28). I get that we aren't supposed to actually solve the question, but is there an "undergrad" or "serious highschooler" breakdown of the math and why its unanswerable? I understand I'm taking a risk by asking as maybe the reason is something so obvious yet I'm missing it...
Here he is on these type of questions:

any language sufficiently rich that to be defined necessarily allows you to ask
questions which don't have any conceivable answer but sound as if they
should we're used to that in a number of special cases we're used for instance in
mathematics except this is a very Applied Mathematics to know that to ask what what frequencies are present in a
signal at a given instance it just doesn't make sense you can't I mean the definition of frequency or how you would
measure it is such that you can't ask that question without specifying a nonzero
interval

And here here is his brief explanation of why this question about zeta zeroes is so frustrating to mathematicians:

here's one which I like to throw at
mathematicians as an example but I warn you people can get very upset at this one uh if somebody
takes set theory as a serious foundational language for mathematics I can pose to him because of
its untyped nature the question are there any simple groups that appear as zeros of the zeta function I've seen
people get very angry at this I've seen people forget why I mentioned it say I didn't really ask it I only mentioned
it I I've had I've had people come back to me two weeks later swearing at me for
bringing up such an absurd question okay that's transparently absurd notice by
the way you have no way of answering it at all even if you took it for the moment seriously until you specify what
definition of group you have in mind and what definition of complex number and then after somebody specifies
them I've challenged people now prove to me that there aren't any simple groups

However, I only have a small introduction to groups, and no serious academic knowledge of the zeta function, so I'm missing out. Is it possible to get a breakdown of the math and moral?
This is from “An Antiphilosophy of Mathematics,” Peter J. Freyd  ~18:28 time stamp

Please do not post meta commentary in your question, particularly when it calls out another user by name.

Freyd is talking about an idea which in philosophy I think is called a category mistake or category error, and which in mathematics does not seem to have a widely agreed-upon name, but which it makes sense to call a type error by very close analogy with computer science.
Here is a simpler and less technical example of the same idea:

Is brown tall?

Is the answer yes or no? Or does it seem like a question which is ill-formed somehow? Brown is not even the sort of thing which could be called tall or short. It doesn't have a height at all! It's an object in the wrong category for this to be a sensible question.
So, the first layer of what Freyd is talking about is that, with a minimum of technical detail:

The zeroes of the zeta function are certain special complex numbers, which are, to be slightly more concrete, certain pairs $a + bi$ of real numbers.
Simple groups are... well, it's complicated to say exactly what they are. You can think of them as certain collections of permutations. The important thing is that they can be defined without any reference to anything that looks like a number. The smallest (edit: non-abelian!) example is the group of rotational symmetries of an icosahedron.

So they are two very different type of objects. There's no meaningful sense in which we can interpret a simple group as a complex number; in computer science terminology (we have to keep importing this because in mathematics none of what we're currently talking about is explicitly given a name) there is no meaningful type conversion from one to the other.
So the first layer is that "are there any simple groups that appear as zeros of the zeta function?" is a type error and so not a sensible question, in the same way that "is brown tall?" is not a sensible question.

The second layer, and the reason he says this makes mathematicians upset, has to do with set theory. Freyd is alluding to the fact that, technically speaking, in the modern foundations we are supposed to be using to do mathematics, every single mathematical object is something called a set, and without wading into the details of what exactly that means, for any two sets $X$ and $Y$ it is possible to ask questions like whether $X$ and $Y$ have any elements in common.
For a simple example we could consider sets of numbers. E.g. the set of odd numbers $\{ 1, 3, 5, \dots \}$ and the set of prime numbers $\{ 2, 3, 5, \dots \}$ have many elements in common, such as $3$, but the set of odd numbers and the set of even numbers $\{ 2, 4, 6, \dots \}$ don't have any elements in common.
However, in set-theoretic foundations, because any pair of two mathematical objects are sets, it is technically possible to ask, for any two sets of any kind of object whatsoever, whether they have any elements in common. So, Freyd considers the two sets
$$Z = \{ \text{the zeroes of the zeta function} \}$$
$$S = \{ \text{the set of simple groups} \}$$
and asks: do $Z$ and $S$ have any elements in common?
This is frustrating on multiple levels. This should be a type error, but it isn't, because set-theoretic foundations don't technically have a type system at all. Essentially all practicing mathematicians behave as if mathematics does have a type system (see e.g. this blog post for a brief discussion), but technically it appears nowhere in our foundations. This is an awkward and unpleasant disconnect between the way mathematics is supposed to work in theory and the way it is actually done in practice.
The answer to this terrible question in set theory also depends very delicately on the precise choices we made for how to "encode" mathematical objects as sets. Again, without getting into the details of what it means to encode a mathematical object as a set, let's use a computer science analogy: every file on your computer is technically being encoded on some level as a long sequence of $0$s and $1$s. So if I had an image on my computer, and you had an image on your computer, there are at least two things we might mean by "are these exactly the same image?"

We might mean, are our images the same size in terms of pixels, and is every pixel of my image the same color as the corresponding pixel of your image?
Or we might mean, are our two image files coded by the same sequence of $0$s and $1$s on my computer as they are on your computer?

I would say that the first question is a meaningful notion of what it means for two images to be exactly the same image, and the second one is meaningless. The reason the second one is meaningless is that it depends on the different choices our two computers are making for how to encode images as sequences of $0$s and $1$s - for example mine might be a .png and yours might be a .bmp - and those choices are essentially "arbitrary." They don't affect the "meaning" of an image file, which is its pixels. The situation is the same in mathematics; the sequences of $0$s and $1$s used to encode files on a computer are very much like the sets used to encode mathematical objects (in that the choice of encoding is essentially "arbitrary" and we could make other choices).
(However, note that this second question is not "as meaningless" as the example "is brown tall?" we started with. In that example it didn't seem to make sense to answer yes or no. With this example the question definitely either has a yes or no answer, but not one that matters very much.)
So, Freyd is pointing out that the mathematician ought to be able to easily dismiss his question as meaningless and a type error, but set-theoretic foundations don't allow us to easily do so. Again there is a disconnect between how mathematics is supposed to work in theory (set theory) and how it actually works in practice (an informal type theory which nobody specifies). Mathematicians do not like to be reminded about this! It's a sore spot. Personally I find it fascinating.
For more on these themes, see this see this recent answer I wrote about a cataclysmic event called the foundational crisis in mathematics which is very relevant context for how things ended up this way.

Thank you. Can I ask, when going from a traditionally non-set mathematical objects like a simple group (even though it is a set in modern terms) to it as a set, can we predict or know what its elements are like?

@Hooman: that's actually a complicated question to answer for different reasons than the stuff in this discussion. Conceptually the elements of a group are certain "symmetries," like the rotations of an icosahedron I mentioned above. But you might ask, symmetries of what? And the answer in modern mathematics is "nothing in particular." Or, what sounds like the opposite but is the same thing, in modern mathematics we think of a group not as the symmetries of any particular thing, but in terms of every thing it is the symmetries of. It's a long (and very interesting) story.

@Hooman: this is the kind of thing that falls under "encodings." The answer to that question depends on the exact choices of encodings we're using. It hurts my brain a little to even think about what the answer is for a specific choice of encoding because we have to go so far below the "abstraction layer" into the "implementation details."

Do these reasons prevent us from knowing the "sizes" of each set which are the elements of S and Z respectively (since everything is sets I'm learning)? As in, if the elements of S were all cardinality 1 (do we know this by them all being complex numbers?) but elements of Z were any other cardinality, S and Z would have no elements in common because none of their elements have the same cardinality, we could answer Peter's question negatively. Sounds like we can't even get that far. (I hope I haven't tripped myself up on the math yet) (I had deleted this comment; adding back for context)

Thanks! This of course just reinforces the view of many (most?) mathematicians that the set theoretic formulation of mathematics is useless. I first learned about types from programming in C++, and loved how strong type checking made the code so much cleaner and easier to understand. And the compiler would catch 99% of the coding errors by simply checking the syntax. Then I began to see how useful "strong type checking" was in pure math. I now wish students would learn how to code in a strongly typed programming language before they take calculus.

Only after all this, did I start hearing about homotopy type theory and all that. I still don't really know what that's all about but if it is a new way to build the foundations of mathematics, it sounds good to me.

Thanks for this, but I am still missing the point.  If asked that question, I'd say "What does it mean to evaluate the zeta function on a simple group?" And I'd expect one of two responses:  "Oh, I have no idea.  I'm just stringing words together in the manner of ChatGPT."  or "The usual classification theorem provides a natural way to associate a complex number to a finite simple group, and I am referring to that." For the first, I'd just ignore the question, for the second I'd have nothing to say (having no idea regarding that non-existent association)  Either way, no existential problem.

Nitpick from a physicist who knows just enough to get himself into trouble:  the cyclic groups of prime order are simple (right?) and there are several such groups that are smaller than the symmetry group of the icosahedron. (Excellent and thought-provoking answer otherwise!)

To (possibly) clarify matters:  suppose I asked "what's the smallest luminous prime?"  Is that the same sort of thing?  To be sure, I'd expect people to challenge me to define the luminosity of a prime but I'd just shrug and say that my question made grammatical sense and that's the only standard in play.  These feel like different types of bad questions to me, but I would struggle to say exactly why.  I guess that, lacking any definition at all, there is no set of "luminous numbers" so this isn't an error inside set theory.  Maybe?

To be clear:  I'd consider that a distinction without a difference.  Both questions suffer from a lack of definition.  Both could easily be repaired by supplying the relevant definitions and, failing that, both are easily dismissed.

@MichaelSeifert: you are right. I am sure Qiaochu meant to say that the group of rotational symmetries of an icosahedron is the smallest non-abelian simple group.

@Deane I wouldn't say it's entirely useless - it's important to know that we can do it with a small number of reasonable operations (just like it's important to know that we can implement the spec for C++ with just x86 assembler operations). But once we've done it, we immediately ignore the particular implementation, since we only do things that are implementation-independent. [...]

[...] Mathematicians don't want to think about the set-theoretic construction of various mathematical objects for the same reason programmers don't want to think about compiler design. It's important that we have one that works, but we refuse to use anything dependent on which one we choose. If there was an unfixable catastrophic flaw in [[ZFC / Clang]], we'd all just shrug our shoulders and move over to [[New Foundations / GCC]].

@HoomanJ: I would say that the most common way of coding groups is to define them to be ordered pairs $(G,\cdot)$ satisfying certain axioms, and the most common way to code the ordered pair $(a,b)$ is the Kuratowski definition $(a,b)={{a},{a,b}}$. Thus the set-theoretic encoding of a group $(G,\cdot)$ is ${{G},{G,\cdot}}$. So it turns out that all groups have 2 elements ;-)

@Michael: Lazzaro is correct, sorry about that. In Lie theory the convention is that "simple" means "simple non-abelian" and I am so fond of this convention that I guess I have been instinctively porting it back into finite group theory.

With you on that convention.

It is upsetting and unanswerable because it is designed to make very little sense, but not none.
It's close to asking "What colour did you eat this morning?", which makes no sense, and everyone can see that, because everyone is familiar with the concept of colour and eating: you eat food, and colours are not food. In the question "Are there any simple groups that appear as zeros of the zeta function?", a layman would not understand what a group or a zero of the zeta function is, but otherwise the question is grammatical, so it sounds as if it makes sense. However, a sufficiently knowledgeable person would know, a (simple) group is an algebraic structure, and the Riemann zeta function takes complex numbers as input, so it is nonsensical to plug a group into the Riemann zeta function and ask whether it is zero. Any mathematician, upon hearing this question, would quickly disregard it as nonsense (as manifested in the comments of this question).
The difference is, in mathematics, fundamentally, every object is a set (at least by modern mainstream convention). A group is an ordered pair, $(G, \cdot)$, where $G$ is a non-empty set and $\cdot: G \times G \to G$ is a function satisfying the group axioms. However, $\cdot$, as a function, is defined as a set, and an ordered pair, is surprisingly also constructed using orderless sets. A similar story goes for complex numbers: every complex number is an ordered pair of real numbers (the operations are given elsewhere, extrinsic to the number itself), so it is a set. In the end, both groups and complex numbers are sets, so you can theoretically typecast a group to a complex number (note, the object, as a set, is unchanged; it is only the context that changes). It'll certainly be meaningless. It'll also almost certainly not be successful, just like how typecasting arbitrary strings into floating-point numbers would almost certainly fail. But who's to say it'll never be successful? Until you have proved either:

there are no sets that are simultaneously a simple group and a complex number, or
any simple group that is also a complex number (equal as sets) is not a zero of the Riemann zeta function,

you cannot theoretically answer "no" to the question. This is where one may start to feel upset (or amused, like myself), because the question should be nonsensical, but it isn't. Moreover, answering the question would only be tedious work with absolutely no benefit. It is uselessly meaningful.
The question makes extra less sense when you consider that there are (potentially infinitely) many equivalent but different realizations of mathematical objects as sets, sometimes with no concensus. It is equally valid to define groups as $(\cdot, G)$. Meanwhile, real numbers (whose construction complex numbers' construction relies upon), although usually constructed as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, are sometimes constructed as subsets (or pairs of them) (i.e. Dedekind cuts) of rational numbers. One may argue the question is ill-posed because of this. One may also argue the question becomes harder to answer, because there are now more versions of simple groups and complex numbers to compare.
So, what colour did you eat this morning? Well, I ate some oranges.

Are these typecasts, like the moving from the context of a specific group to the context of it as a specific set, arbitrary?

@HoomanJ Sorry I don't fully understand what you mean by arbitrary. Could you clarify? :)

I guess to continue with the computation analogy, 'abc' typecast as an integer or binary is a specific integer or binary, but it could be any (finite) integer or binary all things considered. I guess it should be unique too. That's arbitrary I would say, because the specific digits could have an anything (as long as unique and finite). Is a specific group typecast as a set also "coded" so that the connection between the two is arbitrary in a similar way? Thank you by the way

Side note: I've known Peter Freyd since I was a child, and I can attest that he liked being provocative and causing consternation among his colleagues in the Penn math department. I also took a measure theory course from him and learned nothing.

@HoomanJ As I interpret it, you are thinking about what I wrote in my 4th paragraph (2nd to last). I'll say yes, it can be arbitrary, but it isn't arbitrary if you follow convention. Any of the existing, generally accepted construction of groups and complex numbers (and everything they depend on e.g. ordered pairs, functions, real numbers, rational numbers, integers, and natural numbers) would produce a definite, specific, and not arbitrary, encoding into sets. Like, you should encode "abc" by ASCII, or Unicode, but not something you came up with this morning. Hope this helps :)

I would take issue with "every object is a set". I'd say "every object is represented by a set", but I think most people - even professional mathematicians, even those who work in foundations - would agree that "2" is not fundamentally the set ${\varnothing,{\varnothing}}$, that's just how we're representing it in a certain construction.

@Deusovi Good point; I’ll edit it later. But how wrong was I when I used “is”? Because, I think, strictly speaking, if you’re using ZF(C) set theory, anything has to be a set. It’s more like an object, as an abstract idea, does not depend on its specific representation, but it is still implicitly and inevitably a set when you write it down in ZF(C). This feels more philosophical than mathematical to me haha. I’ve regretfully never properly taken mathematical logic or philosophy courses, which is probably I made the inaccuracy.

"if you’re using ZF(C) set theory", sure, but I don't think most mathematicians actually use ZF(C). The natural number 2 is 'the thing that behaves like we expect the natural number 2 to behave (as defined by the axioms for the natural numbers)'; the construction in ZF(C) is just to show that something with these properties is indeed possible to construct.

Because it has an answer
Let $G$ be a simple group. To be a zero of the zeta function, it must be a complex number.
Every simple group is an ordered pair $(S, \cdot)$, where $\cdot$ is a binary operation on $S$. A complex number is an ordered pair of real numbers, and thus both $S$ and $\cdot$ must be real numbers.
$\cdot$ is a binary operation, meaning it is a function, meaning it is a set of ordered pairs. For $\cdot$ to be a real number, it must be an ordered pair of infinite sets of rationals $(L, R)$. By the definition of ordered pair, $(L, R) = \{\{L\}, \{L, R\}\}$. Since $\cdot$ is a set of ordered pairs, this implies that $\{L\}$ must be an ordered pair, meaning $\{L\} = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ for some $x$ and $y$. So $L = \{x\}$ and $L = \{x,y\}$. But this is impossible since $L$ was supposed to be infinite. Contradiction. So $G$ is not a zero of the Riemann zeta function. $\square$
The answer to "why is this consternating to mathematicians?" is left as an exercise to the reader XD.
(Also, fun fact: the above proof still works even if we only use constructive set theory.)

The part that frustrates mathematicians (as far as they use theoretic foundations) is that while it has an answer, it depends on the arbitrary choice of encoding of "group" and "complex number" as sets. Someone else may use choose different ways to define a group (an ordered triple, a model of a Lawvere theory, ...) and a complex number (equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of pairs of rationals, or ...), and while it would admittedly take a contrived construction to make the answer "yes", it is not really a question of mathematics (which as Freyd says is "not arbitrary").

@arkeet Ooh I like that arbitrary/non-arbitrary distinction you make clear. It brings it home.
